# How to write a multithreaded program that calculates average, minimum, and maximum values for a list of numbers provided as command-line arguments?

Tags: c, multithreading, command-line-arguments

Currently I am writing a multithreaded program in C that calculates various statistical values for a list of numbers. The program receives the series of numbers on the command line and will then create three separate worker threads. One thread will determine the average of the numbers, the second will determine
the maximum value, and the third will determine the minimum value.

So technically if I try to execute the code like this:
$ ./multithreadexe 90 81 78 95 79 72 85

The program should report:
82 72 95

However when I run with the previous values it gives the next output:
0 90 90

There are no compile errors or problems detected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 3

// Variables that hold the final results, integer data type for simplicity. Do not change these variables.
int avgNum;
int minNum;
int maxNum;

// Function prototypes. Definition is at the bottom. Do not change the declaration of these functions.
void *avgfunc(void *param);
void *minfunc(void *param);
void *maxfunc(void *param);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Declare an array of integers to hold the numbers passed as command-line arguments.
    int numArray[argc - 1];
    int i;
    // Convert the string arguments to integers and store them in the array.
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        numArray[i - 1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    // Create thread IDs
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    // Create thread attributes
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    // Initialize thread attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    // Create threads
    pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, avgfunc, numArray);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, minfunc, numArray);
    pthread_create(&threads[2], &attr, maxfunc, numArray);

    // Wait for threads to exit
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // Printing the results.
    printf("%d %d %d\n", avgNum, minNum, maxNum);
    return 0;
}

void *avgfunc(void *param)
{
    int argc = 0;
    int *numArray = (int *)param;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += numArray[i];
    }
    avgNum = sum / (argc - 1);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

void *minfunc(void *param)
{
    int argc = 0;
    int *numArray = (int *)param;
    int min = numArray[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        if (numArray[i] < min)
        {
            min = numArray[i];
        }
    }
    minNum = min;
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

void *maxfunc(void *param)
{
    int argc = 0;
    int *numArray = (int *)param;
    int max = numArray[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        if (numArray[i] > max)
        {
            max = numArray[i];
        }
    }
    maxNum = max;
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The system stores the command-line arguments as strings in memory, and creates an array of pointers to these strings.

For the function declaration:

int main(int argc, char* argv)

argv is a pointer to the array of pointers.

The first argument is always the command name. Therefore, the first number passed on
the command line is stored in the second element, the second number is stored in the third element, and so on. Finally, the arguments are stored as strings. In the program, it works with integer
numbers, so it needs to convert the string into an integer, that is why it uses the ASCII to integer function atoi(*argv).

I think that the variables avgNum, minNum, and maxNum are not properly updated with the correct values by the worker threads or maybe it is not properly passing the array of integers to the worker threads through the param parameter.

Could someone with more experience help me to see where I made the mistake?

I really appreciate it

Comment: What value do you think `argc` has in the thread functions?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The value of argc in the thread functions will be the same as the value of argc in the main function, which is the number of arguments passed to the program on the command line, including the name of the program itself.

Comment: Really? What do you think `int argc = 0;` does?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It declares the value of argc to zero. So where should I declare argc?

Comment: You set your argc variables in the thread functions to 0, and then use `i < argc - 1` in a loop... in other words, `i < -1`. Does that make any sense when `i` is initialized to 1?

Comment: Your code currently passes only `numArray` to each thread. Instead, make a structure type. Inside the structure, create a member for each thing you need to pass to the threads. You should pass each thread 3 things: The value of `argc`, the address of `numArray`, and the address of an object to return its result in. (Do not use external variables.) In `main`, make three objects of that structure type, one for each thread. Fill in the structures. Pass them to the threads. In each thread, convert the `void *` it receives to a pointer to that structure type. Then get the members of that structure.

Comment: @Shawn: Initializing `i` to 1 for the loop is fine for the minimum and maximum functions, which assume at least one element and initialize their extremum to `numArray[0]`. In other words, the case of `i` = 0 is handled before the loop begins. (Whether the assumption is justified is another matter.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil The loops never loop because `1 < -1` is false.

Comment: @Shawn: Yes, that is correct. The problem is not the loop structure, its test, or the initial value of `i`. The problem is the routines are not passed the value of `argc`.

Comment: @Shawn So what would be the correct way of passing the values of argc?

Comment: Like Eric said, use a struct that holds the array and its length.